# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: 14.04

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ unzip master.zip
Archive:  master.zip
d095cba29fdbe98d6ed4812998e07d886835f492
  inflating: pi-blaster-master/Makefile.am  
  inflating: pi-blaster-master/README.md  
  inflating: pi-blaster-master/autogen.sh  
  inflating: pi-blaster-master/configure.ac  
  inflating: pi-blaster-master/pi-blaster.boot.sh  
  inflating: pi-blaster-master/pi-blaster.c  
  inflating: pi-blaster-master/pi-blaster.service  
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cd pi-blaster-master
pi@raspberrypi ~/pi-blaster-master $ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

what should i do?

Comment: perhaps you have to run `./configure` before running `make`?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~/pi-blaster-master $ ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: tried `automake` or `autoconf`? Or the `autogen.sh` script?

Comment: You may need to run `./autogen.sh` first of all (it is what generates the `./configure` script from `configure.ac` iirc) - see http://42.oliver-bunte.de/2014/12/04/raspberry-software-pwm-pi-blaster/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the README, the sequence is:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```